# MySQL: How to show records after a specific ID

Tags: php, mysql, web, phpmyadmin

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 2  |
+----+
| 3  |
+----+
| 4  |
+----+
+----+
| 5  |
+----+
```

How do I show records from a specific ID so the list would show 2,3,4,5 or 3,4,5?

I figured to do with two queries in UNION but end up showing 2,1,3,4,5 or 2,5,4,3,1.

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT from table where id in (2,3,4,5)`? :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >= $curID ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 4";
```

If you want to specify how many entries to find, you can use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >= $curID ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $number";
```

Be sure you sanitize the inputs before plugging them into the query. See this post for more info:
[What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: WoW Jared, it seems will do the job. I will try it and let you know. You guys Rock!!!

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (2,3,4,5)

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >= $id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 4
```

In the second query $id is the input from the user. Also instead of LIMIT 4, you can have the 4 taken as user input

Comment: Exactly, but I want to do it with 'Limit' because the starting id in my case will be dynamic stored in a variable, lets say $curID?

Comment: Lets say if there are 100 ids in DB and viewer choose a number 96, how would I show 4 records from 96?

Comment: Are you talking about 4 Columns contained on row 96? Then you're wanting to `SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4` If that's not the solution to your problem, you're going to need to provide alot more information and pretty much an entire breakdown of your table schema.

Comment: Yes, I need to as I am a beginner, basically it is for an assignment for school administration that how they get students list from a specific roll number.